# RStudio and Sweave autocompletion for LaTeX commands?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio

Is there a way to activate the autocomplete mode for LaTeX documents in RStudio?

I know it's possible for JavaScript, HTML, CSS, Python and SQL, but what about LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\sec
```

I'd like here to press <kbd>tab</kbd> so that it autocompletes `\section{}`

```
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are FAQ and support in the website dedicated to RStudio. Try there.

Comment: Much information is on this website, but nothing about the autocomplete function.

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us would be a better place to ask than here.

Comment: Oh look someone already did https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201065558-Greater-editor-support-for-knitr-and-latex-commands and nobody seems to care.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a feature request that needs to be addressed to the authors.

Comment: Have a look at, http://mathatistics.com/2016/02/25/latex-autocompletion-in-rstudio/

Comment: I don't understand how it works, but it seems that Aquamacs can be the solution. What do you think?